# Copying files from Stage to Working Directory in git

Tags: git

In git there is generally more than one way to do a thing.
Broadly git has three concerned areas: The working directory, the stage(index) and the local repository. Every command in git generally moves/copies files from one of these areas to other. While moving files from working directory to stage and to the repository is common, I was wondering about **copying/moving files from Stage to Working Directory**. One command I know for this is the `git checkout -- filename`. This discards changes made to that file in the working directory and replaces them with last staged version of the file. I wanted to know if there are anymore different commands for doing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In git there is generally more than one way to do a thing.

That's right: Git has a large set of tools, with overlap between them.

> Broadly git has three concerned areas: The working directory, the stage(index) and the local repository.

This is also true.

> Every command in git generally moves/copies files from one of these areas to other.

I think this is a bit of an overstatement as many of Git's tools don't: e.g., `git branch` just manipulates branch names, `git tag` just manipulates tag names, and so on.  But there certainly are tools that do this sort of copying.

> ... I was wondering about copying/moving files from Stage to Working Directory

Prior to Git 2.23, the tools for this were somewhat scattered and clumsy.

In Git 2.23, the `git checkout` command was split into two separate, better-designed tools: `git switch` and `git restore`.  The `git restore` command has tools to copy to index/staging-area, and to working tree.  These can be used independently *or* together.

The `git checkout` command has only one form for copying from index/staging-area to working tree, which is the one you mentioned:

> One command I know for this is the `git checkout -- filename`

The `git reset` command is like the old (and still present) `git checkout` in that it does too many jobs and is not packaged well, but it also *can* copy from index to working tree.  The problem here is that to do so, it *must* first copy from commit to index.  (Also worth noting: it only does this with `git reset --hard`, and when you use that mode, you're adjusting the entire working tree, not just a single file.  This mode therefore has only very specific use cases, though they're somewhat common.)

The `git checkout-index` command can copy from index to working tree.  It's not used very often: it is meant as a so-called *plumbing command*, used for writing new user-facing tools.

The `git show` and `git cat-file` commands can extract any internal object, including those in the index.  You can use command-line redirection with these, e.g., `git show :0:README.md > index-copy-of-README.md` or `git cat-file -p :Makefile | wc -l`, to let any of your regular tools work with the data.

Comment: https://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html . If you check on the net(above website is just an example). It says that though git reset command undoes git add, it actually copies files from last commit to the stage. But there is no mention of moving/copying happening between stage and the working directory, so should It be considered?

Comment: The `git reset` command is complicated: in several modes, it only copies from `HEAD` to index/staging-area, but with `git reset --hard` it copies to both index *and* working tree. The problem here is that this can only be used in "whole commit" mode, not "individual file" mode. So it's occasionally useful, but only *very* occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

You may unstage a file (move the file from stage back to the working directory) with:

`git restore --staged <file>`

This is the proposed way from git (version >= 2.23) if you run *git status* on your repository.

Comment: Note that `git restore --staged <file>` is not equivalent with `git checkout -- filename` since the second one is not able to unstage the file

Comment: But `git restore <file>` is equivalent to `git checkout -- filename`, right? because when I tried this command it replaced the changes done to my file in working directory with the last staged version of that file.

Comment: Right, the commands you are mentioned (without --staged parameter in git restore) are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Running `git reset` will remove your changes in the **index** (and also in the **repository**) but will keep them in the **working directory**

For example, lets say you have added some text to a file and performed `git add` to add it to the staging area. If you now run:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

Then the added text won't be in the staging are (and neither in the repository for that matter), but it will still be present in the working directory. However this is not the same as `git checkout -- <file>`, since this command restores the files to the last recorded state and discard the changes without the possibility of getting them back. This is considered a risky command so be sure to know what you're doing when running it

Comment: https://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html . If you check on the net(above website is just an example). It says that though git reset command undoes git add, it actually copies files from last commit to the stage. But there is no mention of moving/copying happening between stage and the working directory, so should It be considered?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to unstage only a particular file you can use

```
git rm --cached <file>.
```

Comment: Sure, this removes the file from the index, but the OP question was how to move/copy a file from the index/stage to working.

To see this for yourself.  Have a certainFile in working, then add it to stage/index.

Then do rm certainFile to remove it from working.

now the file is in stage, but not working.

now do git rm --cached certainFile

where is the file?...any copy?