# What is the best way to copy everything from staging/index area to working directory?

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose I have some changes in my working directory and then I stage all of these changes. Let's call this **state-1**.

Next, I make some more changes to my working directory. Now, how do return to **state-1**? Is there a standard/simple command to do this?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64358193/copying-files-from-stage-to-working-directory-in-git) is very similar but no standard/definite answer on how to actually do it. The closest thing I have found is:

```
git restore .
```

But this command is still experimental, and its behavior may change([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)). So what's the right way to do this?

Comment: You should use the `git reset` command. Read here about reset https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-can-i-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head-undo-commits/34519716#34519716

Comment: `git reset commit_reference` is used to move everything from a referenced commit to the staging area/working directory based on the specified flag. On the contrary, what I'm looking for is to copy everything from **staging area** to **working directory**.

Comment: Indeed, `git reset` is definitely the wrong command. `git restore` is the best one but you can use the index-extraction mode of `git checkout` if your Git lacks `git restore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, although `git restore` is still flagged as "experimental", it is meant to stay around, and there are big chances that `git restore .` will keep doing the same thing in future versions.

---

If you want to keep a trace of your modified files, you can use `git stash -k` : this will save the initial content of your worktree in the stash, and then return your worktree to its index state.

If you really don't care about these changes : you can simply run `git checkout .`, which does the exact same thing as `git restore .`.

Comment: Alright thanks! So, (just confirming) considering all this, `git restore .` is then probably the right way to copy everything from the staging index to the working directory, right? This is crucial because I plan on making aliases such as  `git IndexToWorkingDir` for `git restore .` and a few similar ones-to simply my workflow.